# Updating a number of row with a single SQL query in Oracle DBMS

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table A which has a structure like this:

```
ID   Name  City  zip

1    xxx   wer   134

2    yyy   qwe   234

3    zzz   ert   256

4    www   qwe   567
```

Now i would like to update multiple rows with one SQL query. For instance Query:

```
UPDATE A
   SET zip= '355'
   WHERE id= '2';
```

Will update one row, what if I also want to update row with ID 1 and 4 with just one query, where ZIP are different?

Comment: Please clarify, "where ZIP are different".

Comment: Which values do you want to update? Where will you get the values from? If another table then you can do a correlated update.

Comment: @Colin'tHart For instance i want to update row with id 1,3,4 to a zip that I would like to enter in the query directly.

Comment: @DanBracuk Ah my mistake. I am sorry! I will delete the comment above and edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean that you want to update multiple rows to the same zip with one query, you can use the following:

```
UPDATE A
   SET zip= '355'
   WHERE id in ('1','4');
```

However, if you mean that you want to update multiple rows to zip values this cannot be done without some logic sitting behind which id should get which zip. For example, if you wanted to just do a few different values you could use something like:

```
UPDATE A
   SET zip= decode(id,'1','100','4','400')
   WHERE id in ('1','4');
```

This sets the zip of any rows where the id is '1' to '100', any rows where id is '4' to '400' and so on. You can add as many arguments as you need to. If you want a default value for any not listed just add this to the end e.g. `decode(id,'1','100','4','400','999')` would set any that are not id '1' or '4' (but were not excluded in the where statement to '999').

If you have a lot of different values, then I would suggest creating a reference data table and doing a select from this table as a subquery within your update statement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to update different rows to different zip values. Thanks for the suggestion, I will work on it.

Comment: No problem, if you want decide to go the reference data route and need any assistance, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Please try case condition to update with different values:

```
UPDATE A 
 SET zip=case when ID='1' then 'Value1' else 'Value2' end 
WHERE ID IN ('1', '4');
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the logic for finding the correct ZIP for given ID is in your client code, you can dynamically generate an anonymous block, and pack the appropriate UPDATEs there, something like this:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE A SET zip= '255' WHERE id= '1';
    UPDATE A SET zip= '355' WHERE id= '2';
    UPDATE A SET zip= '455' WHERE id= '4';
END;
```

*(NOTE: Use bound parameters in real code.)*

This will execute in a single round-trip to the server, but contains a lot of (textual) overhead. If you need to update a really huge number of rows, consider [array binding](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html) (if available to your client library).

Comment: Why not generate the single DML statement `update a set zip = decode(id, '1', '255', '2', '355', '4', '455') where id in ('1','2','4');` instead? In any case, be careful for SQL injection.